# Rally State field not mapping to ALM Status field

Tags: rally, alm

*Solved as I was running the wrong config. Doh!

I am trying to find an answer as to why the mapping for the State field in Rally to the Status field in ALM is not mapping. Here is my xml config to show what is being used and where. I'm not understanding why it is not working because I have used the same mappings for Priority and Severity and they are working.

Thank you for helping!

```
<Connector>
    <FieldMapping>
        <Field><Rally>Name</Rally><Other>BG_SUMMARY</Other></Field>
        <Field><Rally>Severity</Rally><Other>BG_SEVERITY</Other></Field>
        <Field><Rally>c_DefectType</Rally><Other>BG_USER_03</Other></Field>
        <Field><Rally>SubmittedBy</Rally><Other>BG_DETECTED_BY</Other></Field>
        <Field><Rally>Priority</Rally><Other>BG_PRIORITY</Other></Field>
        <Field><Rally>Owner</Rally><Other>BG_DETECTED_BY</Other></Field>
        <Field><Rally>State</Rally><Other>BG_STATUS</Other></Field>
    </FieldMapping>

<OtherFieldHandlers>
        <OtherEnumFieldHandler>
          <FieldName>BG_SEVERITY</FieldName>
       <Mappings>
            <Field><Rally>Crash/Data Loss</Rally><Other>5-Urgent</Other></Field>
            <Field><Rally>Major Problem</Rally><Other>4-Very High</Other></Field>
            <Field><Rally>Major Problem</Rally><Other>3-High</Other></Field>
            <Field><Rally>Minor Problem</Rally><Other>2-Medium</Other></Field>
            <Field><Rally>Cosmetic</Rally><Other>1-Low</Other></Field>
      </Mappings>
     </OtherEnumFieldHandler>           

        <OtherEnumFieldHandler>
      <FieldName>BG_PRIORITY</FieldName>
       <Mappings>
              <Field><Rally>Resolve Immediately</Rally><Other>5-Urgent</Other></Field>
              <Field><Rally>High Attention</Rally><Other>4-Very High</Other></Field>
              <Field><Rally>High Attention</Rally><Other>3-High</Other></Field>
              <Field><Rally>Normal</Rally><Other>2-Medium</Other></Field>
              <Field><Rally>Low</Rally><Other>1-Low</Other></Field>
       </Mappings>
     </OtherEnumFieldHandler>

     <OtherEnumFieldHandler>
        <FieldName>BG_STATUS</FieldName>
           <Mappings>
        <Field><Rally>Submitted</Rally> <Other>New</Other></Field>
        <Field><Rally>Open</Rally>      <Other>Open</Other></Field>
        <Field><Rally>Open</Rally>      <Other>Reopen</Other></Field>
        <Field><Rally>Fixed</Rally>     <Other>Fixed</Other></Field>
        <Field><Rally>Closed</Rally>    <Other>Closed</Other></Field>
        <Field><Rally>Closed</Rally>    <Other>Rejected</Other></Field>
           </Mappings>
    </OtherEnumFieldHandler>
 </OtherFieldHandlers>


<RallyFieldHandlers>

         <RallyCSVUserMappingFieldHandler>
    <FieldName>SubmittedBy</FieldName>
    <FileName>rally_csv_user_mapping_test.csv</FileName>
         </RallyCSVUserMappingFieldHandler>

         <RallyCSVUserMappingFieldHandler>
    <FieldName>Owner</FieldName>
    <FileName>rally_csv_user_mapping_test.csv</FileName>
     </RallyCSVUserMappingFieldHandler>
      </RallyFieldHandlers>
 </Connector>

<ConnectorRunner>
    <Preview>False</Preview>
    <LogLevel>Debug</LogLevel>
    <Services>COPY_QC_TO_RALLY, UPDATE_QC_TO_RALLY</Services>
</ConnectorRunner>
```

Comment: By not working I mean that state is not updating its values from QC to Rally.

The log states:

[2015-04-27 12:47:16 Z]  WARN : RallyEIF::WRK::Connector.block in validate - Unused Rally Field Handler found: State

Comment: Sorry for wasting everyone's time. I was running the wrong config.